# how to design database for quiz for multi language

Tags: mysql

I am working simple quiz application. 
question table
question id
question
option1
option2
option3
option4
answer

i want to display question and options in different languages. How to store question and option in different language in question table?

Comment: The term you're looking for is "localization". The implementation will depend on your language and framework for the application.

Comment: i m learning codeigniter framework. i have add question form . form fields are language, question, option1, option2,option3, option 4 , answer. if language is , english then i fill form fields after submit it will stored in database. if i want to enter other language eg: french, hindi  for same question  again i need to fill form like this. is there any solution for this? i have added google translator in exam panel . but some question have mathematical symbol

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your table structure, but I'd think about something like this:

```
question_id   | option_id   |  lang_code  | is_correct  |  text
1             | 1           |  en_US      | true        | this is the right answer
1             | 2           |  en_US      | false       | a wrong answer
1             | 3           |  en_US      | false       | another wrong answer
1             | 4           |  en_US      | false       | wrongest answer
1             | 5           |  de         | true        | correct in german
1             | 6           |  de         | false       | falshe
1             | 7           |  de         | false       | incorrect in german
1             | 8           |  de         | false       | wrongest in german
```

and so on.